# Is it possible to show specific column based on matching data validation?

Tags: regex, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

We have a kitchen ordering sheet and we want to simplify it without over-complicating matters with a POS system. I want to know if it is possible on Google Sheets to have a column from a specific sheet appear based on a matching selection in the data validation.

I have tried a match function and index, but can only get it to show the first cell. Cells B4:B should populate the information on the sheet marked BH based on the validation (Sept 2 - 6, or Sept 9 - 13, etc...); then, in the column marked for NS, it would pull the same info from the same tab. Same for the PCM column/sheet.

I have the sheet linked here:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SDXh359JEklgt4ndP3TK29v4OZSburUyX7IZStCGWec/edit?usp=sharing

Is this possible?

Comment: sheet is private

Comment: I apologize, I just opened it up to edit by anyone!

Comment: This is perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste in **B4** cell and drag to the right:

```
=IFERROR(INDIRECT(B3&"!"&ADDRESS(2, MATCH($B2, INDIRECT(B3&"!1:1"), 0), 4)&":"&
            ADDRESS(COUNTA($A4:$A), MATCH($B2, INDIRECT(B3&"!1:1"), 0), 4)))
```

[image: 0]

---

then for total paste this in **E4** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(
 REGEXREPLACE(""&B4:B+C4:C+D4:D, "^0$", )<>"", 
 B4:B+C4:C+D4:D, ))
```

[image]